# WordTo2DChar ,other than index of function do not use any other string function

Tags: java, arrays, string

Given a para of words (separated by space), create a 2D array where each array in it represents the word. Note that the words are of the same size.

Sample Input #1

```
to2DChars("bat sat put mat")
```

Sample Output #1

```
{{'b','a','t'},{'s','a','t'},{'p','u','t'},{'m','a','t'}}
```

Sample Input #2

```
to2DChars("hi is to")
```

Sample Output #2

```
{{'h','i'},{'i','s'},{'t','o'}}
```

enter code here

```
public char[][] to2DChars(String words){
      
      int row=0;
        int index=words.indexOf(' ');
        int col=index;
        while(index!=-1){
        row++;
        index=words.indexOf(' ',index+1);
        }
        row++;
        char[][] c=new char[row][col];
        int k=0;
        for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
        c[i][j]=words.charAt(i+k);
        k++;
        }
```

Testcase Pass/Fail  Parameters  Actual Output   Expected Output

## 3  Pass 'a b c d' {{'a'};{'b'};{'c'};{'d'}} {{'a'};{'b'};{'c'};{'d'}}

## 4  Fail    'hello'     null    {{'h','e','l','l','o'}}

One test case didn't pass can anybody tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you be more explicit on the expected input and output? Perhaps show us the unit test code?

Comment: @JamesWierzba input is 'hello' and expected output should be {{'h','e','l','l','o'}} my code gives null..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly you didn't take into account single word input. Something like below should work (untested code):

```
public char[][] to2DChars(String words){

  int row=0;
    int index=words.indexOf(' ');
    int col=(index==-1 ? words.length() : index);
    while(index!=-1){
    row++;
    index=words.indexOf(' ',index+1);
    }
    row++;
    char[][] c=new char[row][col];
    int k=0;
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
    c[i][j]=words.charAt(i+k);
    k++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote another solution. If someone is interested in take a look.

```
public char[][] to2DChars(final String words) {

  final String[] splittedWords = words.split(" ");
  final char[][] result = new char[splittedWords.length][];

  for (int i = 0; i < splittedWords.length; i++) {
    result[i] = new char[splittedWords[i].length()];

    for (int j = 0; j < splittedWords[i].length(); j++) {
      result[i][j] = splittedWords[i].charAt(j);
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```